# The difference between "IE9 debug tools" HTML output and webpage source HTML that I got via C#

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer

I'm not the first time here with questions like this.
I have a Volvo auto parts catalog that is implemented as a client application to a local database and works only in IE8/9. I need to find and get some positions displayed in IE.

Here's an example of IE output:
[image: IE output sample]

It's just a table and nothing more.

And here's what I see in IE9 debug tools:
[image: IE debug tools output]

IE shows me full layout of a page where I can see a target table and rows with the data I need to get.

I wrote a simple class that should walk through all IE tabs and get HTML from the target page:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using SHDocVw;

namespace WebpageHtmlMiner
{
    static class HtmlMiner
    {       
        public static string GetWebpageHtml(string uriPattern)
        {
            var uriRegexPattern = uriPattern;
            var regex = new Regex(uriRegexPattern);
            var shellWindows = new ShellWindows();

            InternetExplorer internetExplorer = null;

            foreach (InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
            {
                Match match = regex.Match(ie.LocationURL);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
                {
                    internetExplorer = ie;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (internetExplorer == null) 
            {
                return "Target page is not opened in IE";
            }

            var mshtmlDocument = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)internetExplorer.Document; 
            var webpageHtml = mshtmlDocument.body.parentElement.outerHTML.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return webpageHtml; //profit
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine but instead of what I see in IE debug tools I get HTML code with tons of javascript functions and no data in target table.

Is there any way to get exactly what I see in IE debug tools?

Thanks.

Comment: In IE, you see the resulting page after all the onload() javascript occurs. In C#, you see the page before any onload() javascript occurs. Try rendering the page in a WebView and then parse it.

Comment: Do you mean you see a difference between the HTML as sent by the server, and the DOM the browser built from that HTML, after running some JavaScript functionality? That is correct, they differ. What is your real question, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the original source (the one sent by the server) in "`Script`" tab (this works both on my IE8 and my IE10).

If you do not use AJAX, I think you can right-click on the page and choose `Display Souce` option too.

Comment: OP is asking why he doesn't see the same markup from a C# app that retrieves the page as he sees when he uses IE debug tools. View Source doesn't come into it.

Comment: Isn't it because the HTML tab just display the DOM as interpreted by IE and not the real source behind it?
I thought this display was just a rebuilt HTML with the Nodes in memory (I got ext:qtip attibute disappearing from this view but still existing in the real code).
The html got by the C# app is the real code and not the rebuilt HTML from this view...

Comment: When you use the `Save` option from this view, you have `<!-- saved from url=***** -->
<!-- Generated by F12 developer tools. This might not be an accurate representation of the original source file -->`

Comment: Ahh, I see where you were going with this now. You're saying that View Source should be what the server returned, whereas the HTML tab shows the DOM as currently interpreted by IE. If you edit your answer to make it clearer, I'll undo my downvote. (I can't undo it without an edit being made.)

Comment: I think your answer is only part of the problem. I suspect strongly the problem is related to Javascript not running in the C# request. The DOM as interpreted by IE will reflect any changes the Javascript made.

Comment: The Javascript is not running in the C# request as it's getting the IE process and asking it the current source, so it should show the correct code currently running in the browser. Maybe the modifications to the DOM nodes (as element.setAttribute()...) are not getting back on the original source so the text got is the one without the javascript modifications (affecting only the DOM in the RAM on the first tab). The source this program get is the source sent and the first tab one is like a toString() of the objects.